# Mongoose is not saving elements

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a problem creating schemas and models in mongoose, with mongo db and node.js express. The elements are not saved or it returns old elements. Before this problem it was returning old elements and now an empty array. I don't know if the problem has to do with mongoose or mongodb.

Index.js

```js
    import express from "express";
    const app=express();
    import path from 'path'
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    import { dirname } from 'path';
    const __filename = fileURLToPath(import.meta.url);
    const __dirname = dirname(__filename);
    
    import Product from './models/product.js'
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/farmStand') 
        .then(() => {
            console.log("CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("OH NO ERROR!!!!")
            console.log(err)
        })
    
    app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
    app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
    
    app.get('/products', async(req, res)=>{
      const products= await Product.find({})
      console.log(products)  
      res.render('products/index', {products})
    })
    
    app.get('/products/:id')
    
    const port= 3001; 
    app.listen(port, () =>{
        console.log(`listening on ${port}`)
    })
```

seeds.mjs

```js
    import mongoose from 'mongoose'
    import Product from './models/product'
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://0.0.0.0:27017/farmStand') 
        .then(() => {
            console.log("CONNECTION OPEN!!!")
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log("OH NO ERROR!!!!")
            console.log(err)
        })
    
        const seedProducts = [
            {
                name: 'Fairy Eggplant',
                price: 1.00,
                category: 'vegetable'
            },
            {
                name: 'Organic Goddess Melon',
                price: 4.99,
                category: 'fruit'
            },
            {
                name: 'Organic Mini Seedless Watermelon',
                price: 3.99,
                category: 'fruit'
            },
            {
                name: 'Organic Celery',
                price: 1.50,
                category: 'vegetable'
            },
            {
                name: 'Chocolate Whole Milk',
                price: 2.69,
                category: 'dairy'
            },
        ]
        
        Product.insertMany(seedProducts)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
            })
            .catch(e => {
                console.log(e)
            })
    .catch(e =>{
        console.log(e)
    })
```

product.js

```js
    import pkg from 'mongoose';
    const {Schema, model}= pkg
    
    const productSchema = new Schema({
        name: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        },
        price: {
            type: Number,
            required: true,
            min: 0
        },
        category: {
            type: String,
            lowercase: true,
            enum: ['fruit', 'vegetable', 'dairy']
        }
    })
    
    const Product = model('Product', productSchema);
    
    export default Product
```

Comment: Where are you saving new documents? are you talking about `Product.insertMany(seedProducts)`

Comment: yess, I have already saved the problem, but thank you!